# Open file with blank spaces in filename

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

How  it understands the blank spaces like separated args:

```
            const string args = "";

            string result = args + openFileDialog; //For test purpose only
            var app = new ProcessStartInfo(Application.ExecutablePath, result);

            Proc
```

When I start the other instance of my aplication, I use the argument to read the file using a StreamReader:

```
_fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, false, 512, true);

var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

My log file output is like this (I've removed some info so it's more readable):

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly quote the filepath? Put some `"` around the path, and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with quotes and double quotes. I put a breakpoint and edited the result string. Like in 'C:\...\file test.txt'.

Comment: So you are starting another instance of your application passing in some filename as an argument. So your main method is expected to read this argument and do something with it. Can you show us what are you doing with such argument in the Main method?

Comment: @Yacoub I get the first argument as the filepath. After I get the file path, I try to read with a StreamReader. I'm trying to simplify the code so I can update my question.

Comment: Can you print filePath to the console just for testing, then take its value and then try to see if it exists by trying to open it via notepad

Comment: Your code doesn't fully reproduce the problem you described.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Also note you should be using `openFileDialog.FileName` instead of just `openFileDialog` to retrieve the selected file.

Comment: @MattJohnson I tried to put the minimal code I believed people would see the problem, but thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the arguments with double-quotes. Note the space before the \ like in " \"".

Like this:

```
...

string result = ...;

result = " \"" + result + " \"";

...
```

Comment: I've already tried this. I tried the same with simple quotes. It's adding a \" to the start and to the end of the string.

Comment: It worked when I put a blank space before the \ like in " \"". Please, update your answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: I think that we need to explain why this is happening. It will not make sense to anyone who is reading this why we need the extra space. Can you provide more information? For example, what was the final content of the result variable after the fix? Also, what was the value of the filePath variable in the new process? also what is the value of the command line parameters in the main method?

Comment: "\"" without the blank space simply adds a \ before the whole string, that was the problem.

Comment: Actually, "\"" should have added " not \

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string result = openFileDialog.FileName;
```

File names with spaces are loaded fine.